# Reading an unknown string from a Text Box

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, console, cpu-word

I've got a text box which works as a console (in a form application).

I'd like to run a certain sub when the user types in:

```
broadcast blabla
```

the sub would broadcast the string blabla.
How would the program recognize ONLY the first word?

Would something like this work?

```
If ConsoleInput.Text = "broadcast " & command Then
BroadcastMessage(command)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0):

```
Dim words As String() = ConsoleInput.Text.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
If words.Length > 1 AndAlso words(0).ToLower() = "broadcast" Then
    BroadcastMessage(words(1))
End If
```

**Edit**: If you want to *broadcast* all words it might be better to use `String.Substring`:

```
Dim spaceIndex = ConsoleInput.Text.IndexOf(" "c)
If spaceIndex > -1 Then
    Dim firstWord = ConsoleInput.Text.Substring(0, spaceIndex)
    If firstWord.ToLower = "broadcast" Then
        broadcast(ConsoleInput.Text.Substring(spaceIndex + 1))
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Works great! But how would I do this to find the next 2 words? For example: broadcast 'ip' 'message'

Comment: @Antonios: Then use my first approch which splits the string into separate words. You can access these words via indexer since it is a `String-Array`. For example: `Dim word2=words(1)`

Comment: Ok! So in that case, if I want to us several words as a single string, I have to input it between "quotes", right?

Comment: Your requirement is changing continuously ;) Then you could use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) instead, for example with the regex [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095501/regular-expression-how-to-find-words-and-quoted-phrases).

Comment: Actually, how does Regex.Split split a string into several ones?